# A complex duplicate rows deletion task under two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a difficulty deletion task and need your kind help. 
The database relates to deals sold in different cities (rows over 400.000). My task is to delete the same deal sold simultaneously in multiple cities. However, the same deal may appear several times in a city at different times. The same deals have the same title (at least first 12 characteristics).

Here are simplified data samples

```
id;   city_id;   starting_date;   title;   

1;     A;        30.01.2013;    chain hotel A coupon

2;     B;        30.01.2013;    chain hotel A coupon

3;     C;        30.01.2013;    chain hotel A coupon

4;     A;        01.03.2013;    chain hotel A coupon

5;     A;        06.05.2013;    restaurant A coupon

6;     A;        30.05.2013;    restaurant A coupon
```

I would like to delete **all** the deals sold simultaneously in multiples cities, but keep the deals sold in a city at different times. The following is my code:

```
DELETE FROM `table` 
WHERE `id` in 
(SELECT t2.`id` from
(
SELECT `id` 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY LEFT(title, 35) 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
AND COUNT(DISTINCT `city_id`)>1) 
as t2)
```

The problem for this code is that after running this code, only one row of the duplicated rows are moved. Any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best possible solution. [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/74954/1)

```
delete t.* from `table` t inner join(

select `starting_date`,  `title`
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY LEFT(title, 35) , starting_date
having count(*) >1 and COUNT(DISTINCT `city_id`)>1) dup on dup.`Starting_date`  =  t.`starting_date`
and left (dup.`title`,35) = left(t.`title`,35)
```

The problem in your query was that the GROUP BY clause in the select query is returning only one row.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I was able to comment, as this is not an actual answer. But have you tried to isolate the subqueries to see if your `SELECT`id`FROM`table`GROUP BY LEFT(title, 35) HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT`city_id`)>1` is returning multiple lines? If so, go back a step and check to see if `Select t2.id from (Subquery)` and see if it returns multiple results and so forth.